# ClassCastException after executing stored procedure in java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

I am getting **ClassCastException** after executing stored procedure, written in Oracle, using spring-jdbc.

Here is the code snippet that is giving issue, here data is the List that i get from procedure:

```
for(Object[] obj :data){
                
}
```

Below is the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object

I think the issue is after getting the **OUT** cursor from the procedure How to use it in Java code i.e. how to extract values from it?

Unfortunately, searching the web didn't give me any solutions. What can I try next?

Comment: You are attempting to casting a result set object to an object array.  Without more code, that is about all that can be stated.

Comment: Including the code snippet which gave the error would be a bit more helpful to understand the exception!

Comment: I have updated the question. I think the issue is after getting the out cursor from the procedure How to use it?

Answer (score 0):

`data` is not a list (or array) of arrays. It is an implementation of the interface [`oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleResultSet.html). So you cannot iterate over it using a for-each loop.

It also implements [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), which defines the method `next()`.
Therefore you can iterate over `data` using a `while-loop`:

```java
while (data.next()){
    Object obj = data.getObject(col);
    // do somthing with obj
}
```

The method `next()` moves the cursor to the next row.
`col` can either be the column index or label.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) you can find an example on using `ResultSet`.